# Scale 2D coordinates and keep their relative euclidean distances intact?

Tags: python, math, coordinates, scale

I have a set of points like: pointA(3302.34,9392.32), pointB(34322.32,11102.03), etc.

I need to scale these so each x- and y-coordinate is in the range (0.0 - 1.0).
I tried doing this by first finding the largest x value in the data set (maximum_x_value), and the largest y value in the set (minimum_y_value). I then did the following:

```
pointA.x = (pointA.x - minimum_x_value) / (maximum_x_value - minimum_x_value)
pointA.y = (pointA.y - minimum_y_value) / (maximum_y_value - minimum_y_value)
```

This changes the relative distances(?), and therefore makes the data useless for my purposes. Is there a way to scale these coordinates while keeping their relative distances the intact?

Comment: Could you clarify the question? It is impossible to scale the points and keep their distances intact, so I assume you want to keep the angles between the points intact.

Answer (score 11):

You need to scale the `x` values and the `y` values by the same amount! I would suggest scaling by the larger of the two ranges (either `x` or `y`). In pseudocode, you'd have something like

```
scale = max(maximum_x_value - minimum_x_value,
            maximum_y_value - minimum_y_value)
```

Then all the distances between points will be scaled by `scale`, which is what I presume you're asking for, so if point `p_1` was twice as far from point `p_2` as from `p_3` before rescaling, it will be twice as far after rescaling as well. You should be able to prove this to yourself pretty easily using the Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you want your entire data set to be centered on `(0.5, 0.5)` with a range of `(0,1)` in both axes, it's easiest to think of the total transformation needed in three steps:

1. Center the data on the origin:
   `P.x -= (maxX + minX) / 2`
   `P.y -= (maxY + minY) / 2`
2. Scale it down by the same amount in both dimensions, such that the larger of the two ranges becomes `(-0.5, 0.5)`:
   `scale = max(maxX - minX, maxY - minY)`
   `P.x /= scale`
   `P.y /= scale`
3. Translate the points by `(0.5, 0.5)` to bring everything where you want it:
   `P.x += 0.5`
   `P.y += 0.5`

This approach has the advantage of working perfectly for any given input data, and also filling as much of the unit square as possible while maintaining aspect ratio (and hence relative distances).

Comment: Not sure the first step is correct. Fails when minX/minY is less than 0 and sort of wrong when greater than zero. Try `P.x  -= minX + ((maxX - minX) / 2)` and `P.y  -= minY + ((maxY - minY) / 2)`

Comment: @swdev you're right, it was off, but the right answer is just `(max+min)/2` since we want to find the midpoint and subtract by it. Fixed, thanks for the math check!

Comment: @tzaman Not sure if this one is filling as much of the unit square. Let's say I want to have my points in (0,28) square but using your computation all points are in (13,14) set. I would like the values to be as close to the edges of the square as possible. This approach makes my figure really tiny :(

Comment: @shurrok The math I posted is for scaling it into `(0, 1)`. If you want the result to cover `(0, 28)` you'd obviously need to scale it up by a factor of `28`. Did you just translate it to `13.5` without changing the scale factor?

Comment: @tzaman i did the same as you posted with one exception: in the third point I added += 14

Comment: nvm, i just realized that I just have to multiple the last step by my desire max like this `P.x = (P.x  0.5) * 28` but in some cases, I got NaN as a value so some points are calculated not as they should be @tzaman

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1: Re-Locate the origin**
Let your new "origin" be (`minimum_x_value`, `minimum_y_value`).  Shift all your data points by subtracting `minimum_x_value` from all x-coordinates and by subtracting `minimum_y_value` from all y-coordinates.

**Step 2: Normalize the remaining data**
Scale the rest of your data down to fit within the 0.0-1.0 window.  Find `max_coord` as the larger of your maximum x-value or your maximum y-value.  Divide all x- and y-coordinates by `max_coord`.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean that you are not keeping aspect ratio: just scale to the minimum bounding square instead of minimum bounding rectangle. You should choose the scale factor along both axises to max(dx,dy).

Answer (score 3):

You have to scale them by the same factor to keep the distances the same.

I'd forget about subtracting the minimum (Note: this part is only true if the points are always positive, which is my usual use case), and just divide by the maximum of the two maxes:

```
maxval = max(max(A.x), max(A.y)) #or however you find these
A.x = A.x/maxval
A.y = A.y/maxval
```

Comment: The input values are never negative. I've used the approach you mention as well, but since my points don't go from 0.0 - 20000.0 etc, but more typically 19000.0 - 20000.0, if I don't subtract the minimum value, all the points end up in a corner of 0-1.... I am dividing all the points by the same value though (maximum_value - minimum_value is always the same). If I understand you correctly, that means that they keep their relative distances?

Comment: My approach subtracts the center-point from each range, so you won't have the 'corner' problem. Subtracting the minimum works too, but then the data isn't centered on `(0.5, 0.5)`. Relative distances should be maintained as long as you keep the same scale factor, yes.